# getting oil data via getSymbols with yahoo as source

Tags: r, quantmod

I start with the following

```
data <- getSymbols(x, from = "2000-07-01", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

However, when I do head(data), the data only starts from 2000-08-23

```
           CL=F.Open CL=F.High CL=F.Low CL=F.Close CL=F.Volume CL=F.Adjusted
2000-08-23     31.95     32.80    31.95      32.05       79385         32.05
2000-08-24     31.90     32.24    31.40      31.63       72978         31.63
2000-08-25     31.70     32.10    31.32      32.05       44601         32.05
2000-08-28     32.04     32.92    31.86      32.87       46770         32.87
2000-08-29     32.82     33.03    32.56      32.72       49131         32.72
2000-08-30     32.75     33.40    32.10      33.40       79214         33.40
```

It's messing up some of my code, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

It is a yahoo data issue. If you go to the historical data section of the Crude Oil and try to use a date before 2000-08-23 you will get an error message saying:

> Date shouldn't be prior to '2000-08-23'